# .htaccess redirect main domain and addon domain issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain name maindomain.com

In the main domain I have a blog. The main domain is not active now. So all requests to site root index.php is redirected to maindomain.com/blog using htaccess.

I have this in htaccess for redirection

```
Redirect /index.php http://www.maindomain.com/blog/
Options All -Indexes
```

Everything works fine.

Now I added an Addon domain. The addon domain root folder is maindomain.com/addondomain.com

addondomain.com folder has an index.php. When I am accessing addondomain.com in the browser its getting redirected to http://www.maindomain.com/blog/ How to prevent this?

Comment: Also if I change the index.php in my addondomain.com folder to index.html no redirection occurs to maindomain.com/blog and everything works fine. But I need the file to be index.php insted of index.html in the addondomain.com folder.

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled? You could redirect using mod_rewrite with more flexibility perhaps.

Comment: Just change `Redirect /index.php http://www.maindomain.com/blog/`
to `Redirect http://www.maindomain.com/index.php http://www.maindomain.com/blog/`

Comment: @Jevgenij Evll : mod_rewrite is already enabled.

Comment: @HanhNghien : I already tried that, then even the redirection in the maindomain is also not working.

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(www\.maindomain\.com)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]`

Comment: Yo. Please enlight us : you want to set up your website on example.com and keep you existing blog on example.com/blog am i right ?

Comment: If you have 2 different domains pointing in the same root directory, then you should create a new blank .htaccess file in subdirectory

Comment: >> you want to set up your website on example.com and keep you existing blog on example.com/blog am i right ? ->  That is right, so if someone types maindomain.com it will redirect to maindomain.com/blog.  That is working fine, the problem is when I added a addon domain with index.php in its root folder. When I access addondomain.com its getting redirected to maindomain.com/blog... Thats the issue which I am trying to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your additional domain has a different host: addondomain.com ?

In this case, simply add this condition to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} maindomain.com$ [NC]
```

So the full redirection rule would look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} maindomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule /index.php$ http://www.maindomain.com/blog/ [R]
```

Comment: Now redirection is not happening from maindomain.com to maindomain.com/blog. But addondomain.com is working fine. (that is its not redirecting to maindomain.com/blog/)

Comment: Did you add

RewriteEngine On 

before rewrite rules?

Comment: `RewriteEngine On` - use this exact statement at the top of your .htaccess file

Comment: I added RewriteEngine On, still its not redirecting to maindomain.com/blog